# Left align and center align div

Tags: html, css

I want to left align an image and center align a text in a div.

But I'm getting:

[image]

The text "This is not centered" is not exactly centered.

HTML is as follows:

```
<div id='heading'>
    <div id='heading-inner-container'>
        <img id='logo' src='abc.jpg'/>
        <div id='title'>
            This is not centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#heading {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;             
    display: flex;
    height: 72px;
    width: 100%;                
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(222, 226, 230);                
    margin: 0px 0px 16px;               
    padding: 16px 24px;
}
#heading-inner-container {
    width:90%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
}           
#title {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 36px -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}
```

How can I exactly center the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `transform` rule:

**CSS**

```
#heading {
    position: relative; // Add this
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;             
    display: flex;
    height: 72px;
    width: 100%;                
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(222, 226, 230);                
    margin: 0px 0px 16px;               
    padding: 16px 24px;
}


#title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font: normal normal 300 normal 36px -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/q68rdo2x/)**

Comment: Thank you. But the text is bottom aligned. Is there any way to vertically center the text?

Comment: Yes... just add `top:50%`and edit transform... `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`. I will edit my answer. On the `#heading`add `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` for image and make `text-align:center`

```css
#heading {
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;             
    display: flex;
    height: 72px;
    width: 100%;                
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(222, 226, 230);                
    margin: 0px 0px 16px;               
    padding: 16px 24px;
}
#heading-inner-container {
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 60px;
}
#logo {
    float: none;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}           
#title {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font: normal normal 300 normal 36px -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}
```

```html
<div id='heading'>
    <div id='heading-inner-container'>
        <img id='logo' src='abc.jpg'/>
        <div id='title'>
            This is not centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```